# Plot factors in order with grouping variable

Tags: r

I'm working with R. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- (structure(list(year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L), .Label = c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), 
       class = "factor"), user = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L,
       3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L),
       .Label = c("John", "Laura", "Liz", "Mark", "Martha"), class = "factor"), 
        spent = c(56, 64, 69, 38, 93, 70, 29, 94, 56, 76, 48, 17, 
        74, 67, 100, 29, 16, 23, 10, 51, 72, 35, 77, 83, 17)), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L)))
```

I'm trying to generate a histogram with the "spent" variable on the y-axis, the "user" on the x-axis, and a facet for each year. For each year, the users should be ordered based on the "spent" variable.

I tried something like `df$user2=factor(df$user, levels = df$user[order(df$year,df$spent)])`
But I get an error saying that the 6th factor is duplicated.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a bar plot. A histogram shows the distribution of a single continuous variable (for example `hist(rnorm(100))`.

Your ordering statement gave an error because each level in a factor variable (each unique value of `user` in this case) can appear only once in the `levels` argument. `factor` allows you to set a new ordering of the unique levels of `user`. For example, instead of alphabetic ordering, we can do `levels=c("Liz","Laura","Mark","John","Martha")`). Then `df[order(df$user),]` will sort the data frame by the new order of `user` and `df[order(df$year, df$user),]` will sort by `year` than `user`. However, we can't use `factor` to get a different order of `user` for each `year`.

Based on your description, it looks like you want a faceted plot, but with a different x-axis order in each facet. You can do this in ggplot if you create a new variable that sets the x-axis order (I've called this variable `r` below) and then use the `labels` argument in `scale_x_continuous` to get the desired axis labels.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = df %>% 
  # Convert year back to numeric
  mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% 
  # Sort data into the order we want
  arrange(year, spent) %>% 
  # Create a new variable with the desired row order
  mutate(r = row_number())

ggplot(df, aes(r, spent)) +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ year, scale="free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$r, labels=df$user)
```

[image]

The above plot seems confusing due to the user order changing in each facet. Maybe something like this would work better:

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, spent, colour=user, group=user)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=df %>% filter(year==min(year)), aes(label=user), 
            hjust=1, position=position_nudge(x=-0.1), size=3) +
  expand_limits(y=0, x=2012.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Eipi, thanks for your answer, it works great! :-)